# PHP + socket.io (session, authorizing and security problems)

Tags: php, security, node.js, authentication, socket.io

I have a working php application in which I want to add real-time support. I would like to use nodejs/socket.io to add that kind of functionality. 

First problem I found was how to properly authorize user on nodejs side (user is already authenticated on php backend through PHP session). Using **socket.handshake.header.cookie** on nodejs side i can parse and get PHP session id, which I can authenticate through redis/memcache/database (depending on what have I used to save session information).
 Everything looks cool when user has only one tab/window of the site opened - when having more and using **session_regenerate_id()**, in nodejs the user authenticates with another sessionid key, so I cannot distinguish two tabs by anything other than the socket id they connected with. When user logouts he shouldn't be getting any messages on any tab (because he already logged out on every tab/window from that browser). So on logout message (sent from browser just before the logout PHP things) I should remove all the socket connections connected to the authorized user id. But what if user logges in on two devices (fe. pc browser and an ipad safaris). After logout on one device, he shouldn't be getting any messages on the device he logged out, not on every device. **How can i distinguish connections from different devices/browsers in socket.io?** Of course not using **session_regenerate_id()** would be efficent here, but what can I do if I really want to use this feature?

Another problem I have is rather a security issue (or even question). Let's assume that authorized user in application can see page **example.com/user1** (which is a news feed for user1) and cannot see **example.com/user2** (fe. he doesn't have rights to see it). I'd like socket.io to send update messages to browser when user is on **example.com/user1**, and of course not to send when user is on **example.com/user2** site. On socket.io side I can read the referer address (so presumably, when user is on user2 site he does not get any socket.io connection). The question is: **should I compare the referer address with the rights of authenticated user on node.js side? Or maybe the referer value is *safe* on the node.js side?** Adding another db check on node.js side would slow it down (because almost every request there should be same database check on two sides - PHP and node.js).

Or maybe the whole concept of socket.io + PHP application working the way I presented is wrong?

**UPDATE**

I think I found a way to omit problems with the first question - basically I just add another cookie (besides PHPSESSID) fe. named NODESESSID, which I generate (fe. using uniqid()) when user is authorized. Now authorization on node.js side is comparing PHPSESSID and NODESESSID (both must match). Now, when user logges out he delivers the message *logout* to socket.io and socket.io disconnects all the sockets with NODESESSID. This is like connecting the benefits of regenerating session id and not regenerating session id (but is not vulnerable to session fixation, isn't it?).

Comment: well my guess is that the referer is taken from the http headers, so i wouldn't consider it safe.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue on your second question, did you by chance find a way around this?

Comment: why not control by a session variable the access rights to the pages ? for example user1 can see his profile, but not user2 profile that the user2 choosed not to make public .. 
`$_SESSION["current_page"]="http://www.example.com/user1";
$_SESSION["canview"]=check_user_rights($_SESSION["userid"],$_SESSION["current_page"]` on nodejs
`if(user1.canview){
 // do stuff
}else{
 // do other studff
}`

Comment: GeoPhoenix, storing pages in session isn't good way, because user can be on many sites at one moment (fe. many browser tabs). The question was rather about security issues between node and front-end side (how to prevent user from "hacking" referer address, on which node recognizes the content which it has to send). Vincent, unfortunatelly I did not find any way other than just checking rights once again on the back-end node side.

Answer (score 1):

For your second questions:

the Referer is not secure, as mentioned in the comments.

I hava a similar problem in my application and this is how it works for me.

first, i hava a single-page app where all traffic goes through the socket, but thats not necessary. it should work with sessions the way you managed it, too.

in nodejs onConnect I ask the backend if the user is authenticated and then store the userid into the socket object (socket.data) and also populate a hashmap to lookup sockets from userids directly.

second, i use Redis and subscribe to a redis list from nodejs ([see redis pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub/)). the php backend pushes messages in this list with a userid to address the message. nodejs takes this message (e.g. a new news feed item), looks up the userid in the mentioned hashmap and sends it to the client. so, a user only gets what he is authorized for. the client then decides what to do with the message. if the user is on his feed page, it could add the item. if the user is on someone elses feed, it could simply add a notification somewhere else on the page. it might also discard it.

on the php backend site, this messages are send to redis everytime an event occurs which needs to be shown live on some connected client. if user1 posts on user2's feed, the new item is stored in the database and in the same time is send as message into the redis queue.

this system also helps to reduce DB load since nodejs just need to query a database to make sure the connected user is already authenticated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it all correct: let's assume that we have 200 news feeds (or even make it 2000) that particular user can connect to. So whenever feed gets an update, we first need to check if the user can read that feed (that's a database query, but we can do it on the backside), then when we send him a message, right? The problem is, when user is looking at one feed, and at the moment 2000 feeds will get an update - node js will generate 2000 messages, but only one will not be discarded by the end-user. I think that is an overgrownth of sent messages... Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: maybe i didn't understand your application. do a user gets live feed updates on every page he is visiting and have permissions? or only on his own feed page (like on facebook).

Comment: Basically it should be something like twitter, user wants to get socket.io messages only for pages he has currently opened (so, whenever he is on different browser tabs on page1 and page2 at once , the socket connected with page1 should get page1 updates, and socket connected with page2 should get page2 updates). That strategy will reduce number of messages sent - but the problem is need to redundand check database permissions (once for php backend to give page1 html and the other one is to check if socketio should send messages to the socket).

Comment: ok, understood. but if a user is on a page he is not allowed to see, why would this page open a socket conection in the first place? the backend wouldn't show any feed page, would it?

Comment: no, it wouldn't show anything besides 403 error page or something - but the you wrote: "the Referer is not secure, as mentioned in the comments.". So, user can be on a feed that he has access to and change the socket referer to a feed that he don't have access to and would be receiving messages that he shouldn't be getting...

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can avoid using node.js, and use [phpdaemon](http://daemon.io/), its written with php and work very good.